# Deploying to Android emulator fails when space in path?

Tags: android, cordova

When I run "phonegap local run android", the install part fails with three errors.

The first one references /platforms/android/cordova/run: line 69 No such file or directory.

However the path that is then shown is truncated exactly where a space occurs. It's as though Phonegap cannot read a path which contains a space.

Two further errors reference the same file but lines 32 and 36. Same path error again.

Has anyone got round this path error?

Comment: is those spaces some u set? if so, remove em, spaces are bad. :)

Comment: Yes they are part of the path to a folder in my Documents folder. That folder name contains a space as might many others in a users' Documents folder! Looks like I need to put the project files elsewhere.